Como subo una aplicacion de angular 17 con SSR a plesk web host edition?
Hoola, estoy en mi primer trabajao y estoy desarrollando un app con angular 17, ya tengo todo echo y cree mi archivo de produccion, que esta en la carpeta dist. Ya habia subido paginas a plesk pero estas solo crean una carpeta dist/<nombre-proyecto>/ y dentro habia un index.html y varios .js, y de ahi no habia problema, solo se subia a el servidor y se le indicaba que abriera index.html.
Pero con angular 17 o mas bien con SSR esto no sucede asi, si no cre dentro de esa carpeta hay otras dos: server y browser, ademas de 2 archivos mas, ya ahi ya no supe que hacer, mi conjetura es que debo hacer referencia al index.html que se en cuentra en browser, pero no funciona ni carga, ademas en versiones anteriores de angular nos mandaba el siguiente codigo para el htaccess, ya que plesk esta por apache:
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html

Este se debe quedar igual? o tambien cambiaria.
Te muestro la captura de mi carpeta dist:
Asi se ve mas o menos
la verdad cualquier ayuda seria bueno, gracias!


para resolver este problema note que la estructura que se ponía antes esta dentro de tu carpeta browser, lo que debes hacer es colocar los archivos y carpetas que están ahí

Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente reputación podrás comentar en cualquier publicación. Es mejor dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta. - Desde revisión
